# Microsoft Access 2010: Select most recent max Record ID for each LANID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to filter out this data based on some criteria.

1. For every unique LANID, a user can have up to 2 records. Some users will only have 1 record.
2. I need to select the max Record ID for each LANID.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I get it.  Your expected results don't seem to match your requirement description.  Why do you have 2 rows in your results for `LANID = 'john1'`?

Comment: define `every unique LANID` also define `user`

Comment: _For every unique LANID, a user can have up to 2 records_ per day?

Comment: If the LANID has a Stage 3 or greater, then they may have up to 2 records with the same Record ID. If the LANID has a Stage 2 or less, then the max Record ID should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

So create one query to determine the `max(recordID)` when grouped by `LANID`, then a second query using the first as the datasource joining it back to your table on `LANID` and `max(recordID)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last update date is not duplicated for a given row, then one method is to use a correlated subquery to get the last date and then get the rest of the columns in the row:

```
select sd.*
from sampleData as sd
where sd.RecordId = (select max(sd2.RecordId)
                     from sampleData as sd2
                     where sd2.lanId = sd.lanId
                    );
```

EDIT:

If you wanted the largest record id for the most recent update date:

```
select sd.*
from sampleData as sd
where sd.RecordId = (select top 1 sd2.RecordId
                     from sampleData as sd2
                     where sd2.lanId = sd.lanId
                     order by sd2.lastUpdateDate desc, sd2.RecordId desc
                    );
```

Comment: he's maxing the recordID, not the lastUpdateDate, although my guess is they're always in sync.

Comment: The lastupdateDate will be the same if the LANID has a Stage 3 or greater, and they have 2 records with the same Record ID.